# Построение диаграмы или графика в rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raphael, morris.js

Здравствуйте, у меня есть таблица, нужно построить по ней график или диаграмму. Использую гемы Morris и Raphael.
Вывод таблицы

```
  <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "doc_diagram", data: {doctor: @doctor} %>

  <tbody>
  <% @doctor.each do |doc| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= doc.doctor_first_name %></td>
    <td><%= doc.doctor_second_name %></td>
    <td><%= doc.current_money %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Переглянути', doc %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Вывожу так:

```
 element: 'doc_diagram',
  data: $('#doc_diagram').data('doctor'),
  label: "doctor_first_name",
  value: "current_money"
});
```

Но выводятся ошибки типа - Invalid value for  attribute. Подскажите  как решить задачу пожалуйста.